# Looking for a Chasam Sofer

Tags: sources-mekorot, chatam-sofer

Where is the Chasam Sofer cited as saying that if one "chances upon" connections across various sugyas he is learning, it is a sign of special siyata dshmaya?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works? Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: I heard the Chasam Sofer specifically to chancing upon Parshas Hashovua within a sugya he is learning. Would love to see the source!

Comment: I'll second mbloch's welcome. The more info you can include in the question about what you already know about the source of this statement of the Chasam Sofer's, the better. For example, if you heard it from a chasid, that may be hint to potential answerer as to which of the Chasam Sofer's books it will be in; if you saw it quoted as "the Chasam Sofer wrote", that may help pinpoint it, at least, as something he wrote personally (as opposed to what others heard from him and wrote); etc. The more info you provide potential answerers, the more likely you'll get an answer.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have additional info - I realize it's quite vague.

Comment: I think we had this question before

Comment: Was it possible maybe the Nefesh Hachaim?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26103/if-two-separate-studies-intersect-is-it-a-good-sign

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/119215/source-that-learning-something-about-parsha-is-siman-for-lishmah