# Source that learning something about parsha is siman for lishmah

Tags: torah-study

I once heard that if someone incidentally comes across something relating to the parshah during his regular learning, it is a sign that his learning is lishmah. Does anyone have a source for this?

Comment: I heard of this I think the one who says it is Rabbi Tzodok

Comment: Related/dupe: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104215/looking-for-a-chasam-sofer

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26103/if-two-separate-studies-intersect-is-it-a-good-sign?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I was told that in general, if there are several sefarim or seder limudim that you have and one of them connects to the other, it is a siman that you are learning l'shema. I wonder myself. Great question!